# Black/purple ingredient in stir fry?

Tags: vegetables, food-identification, stir-fry

I've had stir fry a few times lately and have noticed this strange ingredient in it. It is a blackish purple color, and looks a lot like a noodle! The other seasonings have mostly overpowered it so I can't describe its taste.  I think it is a vegetable, but I am clueless.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a picture>?  Or at least say what type of cuisine or region this stir fry came from?

Comment: I should have taken a picture! The stir fry was from a campus dining hall, so I'm not sure what region is is from.  They use it in all types of Asian cuisine.

Comment: Ah, if it is from a dining hall, what you have is a universal product called Mystery Meat.  I wouldn't worry about it.  Just close your eyes and hope for the best.

Comment: Downvoted?? I just now noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wood ear mushrooms maybe? [wood ear](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://0.tqn.com/d/gourmetfood/1/0/t/G/woodears_rehydrated.jpg&imgrefurl=http://gourmetfood.about.com/od/wheretobuygourmetfoods/ig/Edible-Mushroom-Varieties/Wood-Ear-Mushrooms.htm&h=466&w=700&sz=35&tbnid=sDprPnax57pLDM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=135&zoom=1&usg=__MWA0rlIK2XMqrGIu5RqUsjUeUSo=&docid=0LQZGwu3E4zQlM&sa=X&ei=kN9_UrGsEufTiwKM8IGgCw&ved=0CEoQ9QEwBQ)

Comment: I believe this might be it. I've wondered myself too, but after some inspection, it was this (in my case).

Comment: I was a kid when I had it in a stir-fry for the first time. It was love at first bite, so made it a mission to find out what it was, where to get it and how to use it. I still use it all the time.

Comment: I think it may be this, just sliced very thin.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like eggplant to me. It's purplish-black on the outside, and has a very mild taste when cooked that's easily overpowered by other flavours.

[image: Eggplant]

I don't know about looking like a noodle - maybe it's just the way it's cut. But it's a fairly common ingredient in stir-fries.

Comment: Maybe it's just detached skin from narrow slices.

Answer (score 0):

It might be red cabbage. I'm not a big veggie person but I know it's purple lol.